# Using Assignment Instead of Equality - good or bad practice?

Tags: php, coding-style

I know the following assignment in the while-condition clause will work:

```
while ($info=mysql_fetch_array($data_jurisdiction))
{
//some stuff
}
```

`$info` is assigned some value and the while-condition will loop unless the right side of the assignment returns a `FALSE`, `NULL`, `0`, `array()`, etc.

Question: is it good or bad practice to do an assignment where the language syntax expects a equality check? Zend Studio immediately points this out as a warning. What are the pros and cons of each approach?

Comment: "is it good or bad practice" — subjective

Comment: "where the language syntax expects a equality check" — the language expects a statement that can be cast to a boolean. It is convention, not syntax that places equality checks there.

Comment: Not necessarily. There may be some objective pros and cons to this. For example, the fact that Zend Studio flags this as a warning could indicate that this is bad practice. Surely, it must have an objective reason for doing so?

Comment: Which warning is that warning? Does it have a message. Or is it just an unspecified warning?

Comment: To use *`mysql_fetch_array`*  to demonstrate the issue is bad practice here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is often frowned upon because it obfuscates potential issues and can be harder for developers other than yourself to read sometimes. That said i do it often but in the manner of assignment and check like:

```
while(false !== ($info = mysql_fetch_array($result))) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The very statement of question is wrong.

There is no "Assignment Instead of Equality". An IF statement (as well as other control flow operators) is not limited to comparison operators only, but can evaluate almost any PHP expression. And language do not "expect an equality check" by any means. Language expects only a value that can be cast to boolean and compared to TRUE.
There is NO essential connection between `IF` operator and comparison operators. That's two distinct operators which can be used independently.

I.e. comparison without if:

```
$var = $a == $b; // $var now contains boolean value
```

and contrary:

```
if ($a + $b) // addition
if (isTrue()) // function
if ($var) // variable
```

every expression from the above will be evaluated, result cast to boolean and this boolean checked by IF statement.

So, it's all right as long as you understand what are you doing.

Comment: Any ideas why Zend Studio thinks it is prudent to give me a warning about this coding style?

Comment: @snoopy76 Probably because more often than not, it is a mistake? Not a mistake because it's bad style, but a mistake because whoever wrote the conditional probably really did mean to compare instead of assign.

Answer (score -1):

You have spotted what is problematic with that in your question already.

The solution to the problem normally is to use the Iterator pattern.

```
$jurisdictions = new MysqlResultIterator($data_jurisdiction);

foreach ($jurisdictions as $info)
{
    // some stuff
}
```

For every non `mysql_*` database library support for `foreach` is directly available for the resultsets.

Foreach makes the difference between no result and next result more distinct. The Iterator pattern allows to express the validity w/o assigning it to the result variable.

Comment: Yes, I realize there are other ways to express the code. I'm curious as to the practice of using an assignment when an expression is expected.

Comment: An assignment is an expression as well. For looping resultsets I highly recommend `foreach`.

Comment: It's not a `foreach` question. The same issue would apply to doing something like this: `if ($a = $b)` (putting an assignment in the condition).

Comment: Well but what is the question? You should write code in a manner that you can maintain it well and that you don't shoot yourself in your own foot too often. But that depends a lot how well you're doing with certain constructs. There are no general rules. Albeit you can assign first and compare later. As written foreach does that instead of while, for the if you can introduce another variable with a good name `$a = $b; if ($a) { ...`;